# Connection reset when downloading file with Python Requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I am using the following snippet to load an image from internet in the conda environment:

```
image = np.array(PIL.Image.open(requests.get({URL},stream=True,proxies=proxyDict).raw), dtype = np.float32) / 255
```

I have PIL , requests, python 3.8 and numpy installed in the conda environment. While executing the above snippet from *.ipynb file in VS Code, I am getting the following error:

```
ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))
```

Comment: Please provide a small reproducible example (including URL)

Comment: The server (or your network) is refusing to serve you.  This has nothing to do with Conda or Python and certainly not PIL.

Comment: If you expect this URL to actually respond, you may need to switch to either `http` or `https`.